# How to do compare levels (multiple comparisons) of a factor variable when the model includes an interaction term in linear mixed models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, multiple-comparisons

Hopefully, my title is not too confusing. I have two scenarios (ajo) completed after another (scen 1, scen2). A number of participants completed two scenarios in groups of four people. Each group consisted of four different roles, AO, RO, TO and VP, namely. My dependent variable is a questionnaire that asks the temporal demands of the scenario. This was completed after the scenario 1 and then again after scenario 2. My fixed effects are scenario, role and scenario * role interaction and id as a random effect. Now I built a linear mixed model that goes like this:

```r
lmod_temporal_r <-lmerTest::lmer(temporal.demands ~ ajo * role + (1|id), data = nasa_ajo12)
```

My results are as follows:

[image: results]

I find that the interaction term is significant and that the interaction model is explaining more variability in temporal demands than just scenario alone. Everything looks good. The problem comes here when I want to inspect if roles do differ from each other at scenario 1 and scenario 2 in terms of temporal demands. lmer makes AO in scenario 1 as the intercept and compares everything to that. How could I do the other comparisons? Multiple comparison? This `emmeans:: lsmeans(lmod_temporal_r, pairwise ~ ajo*role, adjust =  "tukey")` does every possible comparison, which is a bit too much. I have no use for testing if role RO at scenario 1 differs from VP at scenario 2. I need the comparisons separately in scenario 1 and scenario 2. In addition, it could be interesting to inspect other interactions too. Not only if they differ in comparison to AO but how about the change between RO and VP when changing from scenario 1 to scenario 2. This issue has been bothering me quite long and it is highly appreciated if anyone can help me with this:)

Comment: Read this vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html -- and possibly others. Basically, just add a `by` variable

Comment: @RussLenth oh thank you! I will look into this.

Comment: Must say that Russ´s link was really helpful in case someone is having this kind of mission on hand.